# SquareUp Payment: Can we turn off SSL verification for development server?

Tags: javascript, ssl, ssl-certificate, payment-gateway, square-connect

I am trying to implement `SquareUp` Payment Gateway on a website and using Square Connect V2. When I try to show `SqPaymentForm` form in JavaScript but getting the following error -

> > paymentform:1 Uncaught Error: SqPaymentForm can only be embedded on sites that use HTTPS.

I can see a function named `setSSLVerification` in sample code but it not working and also I can't find it in API. I wonder if there is any way to turn SSL verification.

Can we turn off SSL verification? Like for development server?

Update:
After trying couple of unsuccessful things, I finally purchased SSL for dev server. As that's the easiest and quick solution. Thanks everyone for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `localhost` for testing payment forms, but you are not able to use other development environments (like external testing servers). I'd recommend either testing from your local machine, or getting a free certificate with a service like [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/)

Comment: Not really related to this anymore though if you post a thing twice from multiple accounts you can either leave it be or do a custom flag; No need to vandalize it in an edit :P

Comment: Yeah I couldn't figure out how to delete the post from the temp account and then I deleted the temp account and lost hope. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

just use following code.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

in your c# code for bypass the security of HTTPS.